# How to encrypt payload file streamingly via WSO2 ESB

Tags: wso2-esb

I have to implement a scenario by using WSO2 ESB, as encrypting the binary payload streamingly while response to the client side (I assume the content-type in the case is Application/Octet-Stream), below is some details by my thought:

1. An Endpoint like "http://myhost/backend/" which provides business functionality;
2. A proxy which pass messages through the endpoint;
3. I attempt to write an OutSequence to check the Content-type: if the Content-Type matches `Application/Octet-Stream`, invoke my customized class mediator to encrypt the fileStream Streamingly and response.

I have no idea on how to write the class mediator to make it implemented? How could I get/read the file stream from the message as well as how to put the outputStream back to the response while I could only see `mc.getEnvelope().getBody()` in mediation method? Below is my current mediator which doesn't work.

```
public boolean mediate(MessageContext mc) {
    org.apache.axis2.context.MessageContext amc = ((Axis2MessageContext) mc).getAxis2MessageContext();
        try {
            String contentID = amc.getAttachmentMap().getAllContentIDs()[0];
            DataHandler dh = amc.getAttachment(contentID);
            dh.getDataSource().getName();
            InputStream is = null;
            try {
                is = dh.getInputStream();
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
                String line = null;
                while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    System.out.println("client read:" + line);
                }

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } 
    }
    return true;
}
```

Many thanks if anybody with experience would kindly help.

Comment: Your question is very unspecificand most likely not answered in SO, please provide some code with what you have tried yet...

Comment: Thank you @Andreas! I will go on to paste my codes here while working around the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Pasted my current solution for anyone else who confronts similar issue.
In the mediator, I read the file content from response stream via OMText.InputStream and use net.lingala.zip4j package to write a zip file(in memory) with the raw file encrypted; Finally I write the zip file content as ByteArray back to the OMElement of the soap message.

```
    public boolean mediate(MessageContext mc) {
    System.out.println("========================Mediator log start================================");
    org.apache.axis2.context.MessageContext amc = ((Axis2MessageContext) mc).getAxis2MessageContext();
    try {
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        Map<String, String> responseHeaders = (Map<String, String>) amc.getProperty("TRANSPORT_HEADERS");
        String rawFileName = "";
        String[] contentDisps = responseHeaders.get("Content-Disposition").split(";");
        for (String item : contentDisps) {
            System.out.println("item::" + item);
            if (item.trim().startsWith(CONTENT_DISPOSITION_FILENAME)) {
                rawFileName = item.substring(item.indexOf("\"") + 1, item.length() - 1);
                break;
            }
        }
        responseHeaders.put(
            "Content-Disposition",
            responseHeaders.get("Content-Disposition").replace(rawFileName,
                rawFileName.substring(0, rawFileName.lastIndexOf(".")) + ".myzip"));
        OMElement binaryPayload =
            amc.getEnvelope().getBody()
                .getFirstChildWithName(new QName("http://ws.apache.org/commons/ns/payload", "binary"));
        OMText binaryNode = (OMText) binaryPayload.getFirstOMChild();
        DataHandler dataHandler = (DataHandler) binaryNode.getDataHandler();
        InputStream is = dataHandler.getInputStream();
        ByteArrayOutputStream responseOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        ZipOutputStream zipOutputStream = getZipOutputStreamInstance(responseOutputStream, rawFileName);
        // write to zipOutputStream
        byte data[] = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
        int count;
        while ((count = is.read(data, 0, BUFFER_SIZE)) != -1) {
            zipOutputStream.write(data, 0, count);
            zipOutputStream.flush();
        }
        zipOutputStream.closeEntry();
        zipOutputStream.finish();
        InputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(responseOutputStream.toByteArray());
        DataHandler zipDataHandler = new DataHandler(new StreamingOnRequestDataSource(in));
        OMFactory factory = OMAbstractFactory.getOMFactory();
        OMText zipData = factory.createOMText(zipDataHandler, true);
        zipData.setBinary(true);
        binaryPayload.getFirstOMChild().detach();
        binaryPayload.addChild(zipData);
        amc.setProperty("TRANSPORT_HEADERS", responseHeaders);
        System.out.println("========================Mediator end==================================");
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println("exception found here:");
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: I am not sure if it could be optimized somewhere around I wrote the zip file bytes back to the message. It now seems that the InputStream object read all the bytes one time from my OutputStream. Appreciate if anybody could give comments on it.